# Prime number python nested loops

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am having some problems with this code that should print all the prime numbers that are smaller than 50 using nested loops.

Here is the code:

```
i = 2
while(i < 50):
     j = 2
     while(j <= (i/j)):
          if not(i%j): 
               break
          j = j + 1
          if (j > i/j): 
               print(i, " is prime")
     i = i + 1
```

Its output is:

```
2 is prime
3 is prime
5 is prime
7 is prime
11 is prime
13 is prime
17 is prime
19 is prime
23 is prime
29 is prime
31 is prime
37 is prime
41 is prime
43 is prime
47 is prime
```

So after 3, j should be 2 and i should be 4. Then it's not a prime number, so it goes back to the while loop.

And the process starts over. j and i should be incremented by one. So j should be 3 and i should be 5, 5 is prime, then it increments again to 6.

So j should still be 3 and i should be 6. But (3 <= (6/3)) <-- this is not true, so it goes to if statement and 3 which is j is bigger than 2 which is i/j, which means 6 should be prime.

But it's not. You can tell that by common sense. And I want to know what part I did wrong here. Did I miss any increments here? Thank you.

Comment: Given that your program produced the correct output, it is not entirely clear why you think that something is wrong. Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, I know that program is right and the output is correct, but I want to figure out what I am thinking wrong*.

Comment: Oh I see. Why don't you reformat the narrative so that: (1) there's one operation per line; (2) each line would show what you think the resultant values of `i` and `j` are. This would make your narrative *much* easier to follow (and might even help you locate the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to post the correct syntax for the code.

```
 i = 2
 while(i < 50):
      j = 2
      while(j <= (i/j)):
          if not(i%j): 
               break
          j = j + 1
          if (j > i/j): 
               print(i, " is prime")
      i = i + 1
```

By writing the code like this, we are able to do several things. The first thing we are able to do is get a nice visual of what is inside of what, instead of assuming anything. The second thing that we are able to do is see what is being **incremented** where.

Now, let us approach what is going on inside of this code. The first to realize is that we are starting off with i=2. We are then initializing a while loop that is going to stop when i is greater than 50.

So, now we are inside of the first while loop, and the next thing we are doing is calling **j**. This variable is equal to 2, as we can see. Not only is it equal to 2, but every time we go down to the bottom of this FIRST WHILE LOOP THAT ENDS WHEN i >=50, we go back to the start and reinitialize j to be 2 again.

This means that j is never going to start out to be two, even though we are adding to j in the SECOND (NESTED) while loop.

Everything from here should make sense, if I understood your question right. The only thing that is weird about this code, in my opinion is the:

```
  if not (i%j)
```

This seems a little odd, for it would be more clerical if it said:

```
  if (i%j == 0):
       break
```

If you have any other questions, please feel free to ask. And if you find this helpful, feel free to accept it as your answer :)

Comment: I reckon if not(i%j) means if i%j is 0 that means it's true in if not (i%j) which means it's divided equally, not having remainders. Well, for me, what you wrote makes a little bit more sense, but both are fine with me. I understand it. And thank you, I figured out what I was thinking wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The indented code is as follows.

```
i = 2  
while(i < 50):  
    j = 2  
    while(j <= (i/j)):  
        if not(i%j):   
            break  
        j = j + 1  
    if (j > i/j) :   
        print(i, " is prime")  
    i = i + 1
```

In your code, `j` is getting initialized to 2 with every increment of `i`.
See this snippet `if not(i%j): break`
If any `j` divides `i`, the `if not(i%j)` becomes `true` and the loop breaks but `j <= (i/j)` still holds else control wouldn't have entered this loop. So control skips  `print(i, " is prime")`

So only way `if(j > i/j)` becomes `true` is when above loop never breaks. That would mean `i` didn't get any divisor, hence `i` is a prime.

Answer (score 0):

I made this infinite prime number generator:

```
def primes_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        for x in range(2, n): 
            if n % x == 0:
                #not prime
                break
        else: 
            #prime
            yield n
        n+=1
```

you can use it like:

```
primes = primes_iterator()
for prime in primes:
    print(i)
```